# SQL query to fetch mutliple columns and multiple condtions

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query which will display columns from multiple tables based on multiple condtions. i tried with join statement but returns some error. then i tot of writing it using basic methods.

Pl find the table layout below:

Table AA
a|  b|  id| st_aa|

Table BB
b|  c|  st_bb|

Table CC
c|  st_cc|

Table OO
id| st_oo|

Five tables are in total.

- AA, BB, CC, OO, HH
- AA and BB will be linked with common value - b
- BB and CC will be linked with common value - c
- AA and OO will be linked with common value - id

one record in OO can have multiple records in AA, ie OO to AA relation is 1..n

i wanted to list down records from AA BB CC & OO

- first cdn - id in AA to be listed from most recent entry.
- In the above result, i can get record from AA upon BB upon CC

Final result to be as:

```
AA.a, AA.st_aa, BB.b, BB.st_bb, CC.c, CC.st_cc, OO.id, OO.st_OO
```

PS: unable to post images

Attempted queries:

```
 select AA.a, AA.st_aa, BB.b, BB.st_bb, CC.c, CC.st_cc, 
from AA, BB, CC
inner join BB ON BB.b=AA.b
inner join CC on CC.c=BB.c
where OO.i in (select OO.i from AA group by OO.i having count(*)>0) order by OO.i desc
```

Second one:

```
select AA.a, AA.st_aa, BB.b, BB.st_bb, CC.c, CC.st_cc, OO.i, OO.st_oo
from AA, BB, CC, OO
where AA.a in (select AA.i from AA where AA.i in (select AA.in from AA group by AA.i having count (*) > 0)) AND (AA.b=BB.b AND BB.c=CC.c) order by OO.i desc
```

Comment: If one record in `OO` can have multiple matching ids in `AA`, then how do you tell which record in `AA` is the most recent? Is there a version, or a timestamp?

Comment: order by OO.i desc won't work??

Comment: You said "first cdn - id in AA to be listed from most recent entry". What does "first cdn" mean?

Comment: primary filter..From this outcome i need to fetch second bullet point

Comment: ill be honest. I'm totally confused what you want to achieve. If you can write it in a clearer way I will try to help.

Comment: You forgot to join OO :-) So do I understand this correctly: you want to find the last AA, then get its OO and for this OO you want to display all corresponding AAs with their BBs and CCs. Yes?

Comment: exactly @ Thorsten Kettner...What hapening now is when i have only AA and OO in my query, results are correct. 67 records in total. But when i m joining, duplicates are coming - around 400.. i just used distinct and got to know somewhere something is wrong

Comment: @ sarin
There are four tables. A, B, C, D. A and B have a common column. That's how they have a relation. Similarly B and C. In addition A and D is also have a relation. Logically one record in C can have one or multiple record in B, one record in B can have one or more records in C. One record in D can have 1 or more records in A. A and D is having a commong key. First get this key. Get all A's of this key, for those get all B and C.. :| I actually have prepared an image of the table wit releations but unable to post due to unsufficient privilleges :(

Comment: @rohit330 - you haven't said what `OO.i` IS.. Are you saying that you want the record with the maximim OO.i per OO.id ? You REALLY need to post the table structure (type it out if you can't include an image) and some sample data and expected results.

Comment: As to StevieG's original remark: IDs are usually not supposed to contain any information beside identifying a record. But if you know it to be guaranteed that a higher ID will always indicate a later entry then you could use it thus, rohit330. However, to find the last AA you would look for the highest AA.id, not the highest OO.id, right?

Comment: @ StevieG Sorry, it was clear in my pic. bt not present. AA and OO contians common column i. So basically AA.i and OO.i will be same.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner, Actually here AA.id and OO.id would be same. Both AA and OO would have sepearte IDs of its own which normally have higher value..as you mentioned..

Comment: @Thorsten - yes, I know what a key is. The OP said that there is a 1..n relationship between `AA` and `OO`, with id as the common column. Meaning that there must be multiple records with the same id in the `AA` table, so id is the key of the `OO` table, not `AA`. This would be so much easier with a simple layout in the question.

Comment: Guys one moment..i m trying to represent the layout using text..Sry, sometimes things are beyond words :|

Comment: @StevieG: Yes, sorry I should have addressed my comment explicitely to rohit330. I kind of tried to support your statement. And yes, the latest OO (i.e. highest OO ID) is not necessarily the latest AA (highest AA ID). Just taking the highest OO ID may work for rohit, but is certainly no general sulotion for the problem described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the statement: Get the maximum id of AA, assuming this to be the last entered AA. Then get its OO, the OO's AAs and their BBs and CCs:

```
select AA.a, AA.st_aa, BB.b, BB.st_bb, CC.c, CC.st_cc, OO.i, OO.st_oo
from OO 
inner join AA on AA.i = OO.i
inner join BB on BB.b = AA.b
inner join CC on CC.c = BB.c
where OO.i = (select max(i) from AA);
```

Or get the ID from OO (which should be faster due to less records):

```
select AA.a, AA.st_aa, BB.b, BB.st_bb, CC.c, CC.st_cc, OO.i, OO.st_oo
from OO 
inner join AA on AA.i = OO.i
inner join BB on BB.b = AA.b
inner join CC on CC.c = BB.c
where OO.i = (select max(i) from OO);
```

EDIT: Having thought about it, both statements above look for the latest OO entry actually. In case AAs can be added to an OO later, the latest AA entry may lead to an OO other than the latest OO entry. So here is the corrected statement:

```
select AA.a, AA.st_aa, BB.b, BB.st_bb, CC.c, CC.st_cc, OO.i, OO.st_oo
from OO 
inner join AA on AA.i = OO.i
inner join BB on BB.b = AA.b
inner join CC on CC.c = BB.c
where OO.i = 
(
  select latest_AA.i 
  from AA latest_AA 
  where latest_AA.id_AA = (select max(all_AA.id_AA) from AA all_AA)
);
```

I have also added table aliases and added these as qualifiers to the inner selects so to make sure not to confuse the dbms by using the same table and column names again.

Comment: thnx Thorsten..that worked..i made it as list result by specifying OO as in statement...wrked...where i went wrong..i think i lack some basic info...

Comment: invalid identifier comes when there is no common value matched while trying to join?? I mean, i m trying to expand the above query to some more tables..where relation with table HH will be either AA key or BB key or CC key. So i tried inner join AA on AA.i = HH.i. HH.i can be null or can have a match. but i m getting invalid identifier for HH.i Why it doesn't knw abt HH table at this moment..cos we din get any match??

Comment: i mean, in the above query "FROM" contains only OO. How system get to knw abt BB and CC while inner join is executing (second and third)..

Comment: JOINS: We select FROM OO. Then we JOIN AA. To join means: Look for records in AA where the ON criteria matches. The ON criteria is AA.i = OO.i . So for each OO record we look for AA records where the field i in AA equals the field i in OO. Three possibilities: Either no matching AA is found, then the OO record gets removed from the result list. Or there is one record matching, then the AA record gets combined with the OO record. Or there is more than one record matching. Then the OO record gets multiplied so that every matching AA record gets combined with one of the OO clones.

Comment: As to joining HH: You say that HH will either be related to AA or BB or CC. That would be: JOIN HH on HH.x = AA.x or HH.x = BB.x or HH.x = CC.x . (Replace x with the columns that link HH to the other tables). OR do you want to join one HH to the AA, one HH to the BB and one HH to the CC? Then you would have to join HH multiple times using aliases: JOIN HH HHA on HHA.x = AA.x JOIN HH HHB on HHB.x = BB.x JOIN HH HHC on HHC.x = CC.x .